# Inserting into database from php

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm trying to insert data to my SQL Server database from PHP. I don't get any error, but data is not applied to db. I was trying with the same query but reformed to normal database query and it worked so I assume there is something wrong with my code:

```
$query1 = "
   INSERT INTO KPI(KPI_new_name, KPI_definition, KPI_tech_name) 
   VALUES('$KPI_new_name','$KPI_definition','$KPI_tech_name')
";

$query2 = "
   INSERT INTO ReportsKpiRel(Report_Id, KPI_Id) 
   select r.Report_Id, kpis.KPI_Id 
   from Reports r 
   inner join ReportsKpiRel RKR on r.Report_Id = RKR.Report_Id
   inner join KPI kpis on RKR.KPI_Id = kpis.KPI_Id
   where r.Report_Id = '".$repid."' and kpis.KPI_new_name = '".$KPI_new_name."'
";

$qresult = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1); 
if ($qresult)
{
  $qresult2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query2); 
  if($qresult2)
  {
    echo "Success!";
  }
  else
    echo "Failed!";
}
else
echo "error!";
```

First query goes smoothly. Second is not working. Have you got any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Please provide your tables structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original answer:**

You need to check for errors after each `sqlsrv_query()` call. But, the more important issue with your approach, is that your code is open to possible SQL injection attacks. Always try to use parameterized queries. As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15), the *sqlsrv_query function is well-suited for one-time queries and should be the default choice to execute queries unless special circumstances apply* and *sqlsrv_query function does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries*.

The following code, based on the code in the question, is a possible solution to your problem:

```
<?php
$query1 = "
    INSERT INTO KPI(KPI_new_name, KPI_definition, KPI_tech_name) 
    VALUES(?, ?, ?)
";

$query2 = "
    INSERT INTO ReportsKpiRel(Report_Id, KPI_Id) 
    select r.Report_Id, kpis.KPI_Id 
    from Reports r 
    inner join ReportsKpiRel RKR on r.Report_Id = RKR.Report_Id
    inner join KPI kpis on RKR.KPI_Id = kpis.KPI_Id
    where r.Report_Id = ? and kpis.KPI_new_name = ? 
";

$params1 = array($KPI_new_name, $KPI_definition, $KPI_tech_name);
$result1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1, $params1);
if ($result1 === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}   

$params2 = array($repid, $KPI_new_name);
$result2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query2, $params2);
if ($result2 === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

echo "Success!";    
?>
```

**Update:**

It seems that you have a different problem. So, if you want to handle `many-to-many` relationship and the `KPI` table has an identity column, you need to get the generated value using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`:

```
<?php
// INSERT into KPI
$query1 = "
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO KPI(KPI_new_name, KPI_definition, KPI_tech_name) 
    VALUES(?, ?, ?);
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS KPI_Id
";
$params1 = array($KPI_new_name, $KPI_definition, $KPI_tech_name);
$result1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1, $params1);
if ($result1 === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$kpiid = $row['KPI_Id'];

// INSERT into ReportsKpiRel
$query2 = "
    INSERT INTO ReportsKpiRel(Report_Id, KPI_Id) 
    VALUES (?, ?) 
";
$params2 = array($repid, $kpiid);
$result2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query2, $params2);
if ($result2 === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}   
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it's still not working. First query goes to database but second is not. Without any errors.

Comment: @maestrostas21 Well, probably the second `SELECT` statement (`select r.Report_Id, kpis.KPI_Id from Reports r inner join ReportsKpiRel RKR on r.Report_Id = RKR.Report_Id inner join KPI kpis on RKR.KPI_Id = kpis.KPI_Id where r.Report_Id = ? and kpis.KPI_new_name = ? `) doesn't return any rows.

Comment: Yes, but why? The same query in managment studio works fine.

Comment: @maestrostas21 What are the actual values of `$repid` and `$KPI_new_name` variables (what does `var_dump($repid)` and `var_dump($KPI_new_name)` output)? If possible, include this information in the question.

Comment: Now I see that there is something wrong with query. It's not working. I'll try to make it work.

Comment: My error was that i wanted to add data to table KPI and link it dynamically with table Reports by many to many relationship table ReportsKpiRel but my query works only if data is actually in database, it's not adding new data. I have to figure how to create query which works that way.

Comment: @maestrostas21 You probably want to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. The answer is updated.

Comment: Works like a dream. Thank you very much Zhorov